# automatically add version changing table note in R Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

need your help for a little problem, I'm using R Sweave to generate dynamic report, and the code is :

```
industryTable<-data.frame("Industry" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$industryname,
                      "Freq" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$Freq,
                      "Perc" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$Perc,
                      "Industry" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$industryname,
                      "Freq" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$Freq,
                      "Perc" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$Perc)
names(industryTable)<-c("Industry", "Freq","Perc","Industry", "Freq","Perc")
add.to.row <- list(pos = list(nrow(industryTable)), command = NULL)
comm <- paste0("\\hline \n \\multicolumn{",dim(industryTable)[2],"}{l}",
               "{\\scriptsize{Matching-Method:Pscore, Base-Year:0,Matching-Interval:0.9-1.10,Log:T,Trim:F}} \n")
add.to.row$command <-comm
print(xtable(industryTable,caption = "Distribution of Privatization Across Manufacturing", label = "table:industry",align = c("c","p{4.5cm}","c","c","|p{4.5cm}","c","c"),digits = c(0,0,0,2,0,0,2)),caption.placement="top", include.rownames = FALSE,add.to.row = add.to.row,hline.after=c(-1, 0))
```

I  need to put and note at the bottom of the table, what I' currently doing is using the add.to.row

```
add.to.row <- list(pos = list(nrow(industryTable)), command = NULL)
    comm <- paste0("\\hline \n \\multicolumn{",dim(industryTable)[2],"}{l}",
                   "{\\scriptsize{Matching-Method:Pscore, Base-Year:0,Matching-Interval:0.9-1.10,Log:T,Trim:F}} \n")
```

it works fine, however, I have 7 tables  in each 32 versions of data combination need exactly the same note format like the one here, the table content and format are different, but for the 7 tables of a given data combination, the table note is exactly the same,which is "Matching-Method:Pscore, Base-Year:0,Matching-Interval:0.9-1.10,Log:T,Trim:F", is there a convenient way of achieving this without of copy paste, cause it's tedious and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a function?

```
make_table <- function(industryTable) {
   l =  list(pos = list(nrow(industryTable)), command = NULL)
    comm <- paste0("\\hline \n \\multicolumn{",dim(industryTable)[2],"}{l}",
                   "{\\scriptsize{Matching-Method:Pscore, Base-Year:0,Matching-Interval:0.9-1.10,Log:T,Trim:F}} \n")
   l$command <-comm
   xtable(industryTable, 
           caption = "Distribution of Privatization Across Manufacturing", 
           label = "table:industry",align = c("c","p{4.5cm}","c","c","|p{4.5cm}","c","c"),digits = c(0,0,0,2,0,0,2)), 
           caption.placement="top", 
           include.rownames = FALSE, 
           add.to.row = l, hline.after=c(-1, 0)
}
```

So

```
print(make_table(industryTable))
```

Comment: thanks for your response @csgillespie, this is a good way to think nut it;s not what I  want, sorry for ambiguous describe of my question, I would correct it right now, and please continue to help.